# Define the sentence

Tags: sentence

Is the following sentence COMPLEX or COMPOUND? Sentence: They sat beside the fire when it was cold. I feel "it was cold" is a subordinate clause.

Answer (score 1):

Complex. *When* is a subordinate conjunction, making ***when it was cold*** your subordinate clause. ***They sat beside the fire*** is the independent clause, and the existence of both an independent and a subordinate clause meets the definition of a ***complex*** sentence.